# Regular Expression in Dialogflow - Count anything in a string

Tags: regex, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-cx

I'm trying to build a RegEx and put in an entity in Dialogflow that checks that the number of characters in a string (I also need whitespaces, numbers and specials) are between 0 and 130.

The following regular expression is correct, but Dialogflow tells me that "*Regular expression match is too broad*":

**^(.){0,130}$** or **^([\s\S]){0,130}$**

Is there a way doing this without coding?

Comment: Does it not like the `.` ? If you try `\w` that gets you alpha numeric (but no specials).  If `\w` works then we can expand to `[\w!@#$%^.....]` to add the specials you want.  Just thinking that error is complaining about `too broad` and `.` is the only broad thing.  And you can actually just try `[\x20-\x7E]`  which is the hex for basic latin character set (what you see on your keyboard).  If that works let me know and I'll write up a nice answer with it :)

Comment: And `^.{0,130}$`?

Comment: Programming languages usually have a `Length` method or property which returns the number of characters inside the string. Isn't it available in your case?

Comment: Hi @MostafaF.Rad, Regular expressions cannot be given without coding. For your requirement, you can try this regex `^(\w\W\d\D\s\S.){0,130}$` or `^(\s,\S){0,130}$`. The  `.` is very broad that covers all the characters and a regular expression can have a maximum of 1024 characters.Let me know if that fulfills your requirement.